# Access Kubernetes Dashboard using kubectl proxy remotly for multiple user

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-dashboard

I have setup kubernetes cluster in EKS. API server access is in private mode. I have bastion host from which i can run kubectl commands. I want to access kubernetes dashboard remotly.

One thing i can do is ssh -L localhost:8001:127.0.0.1:8001 @ kubectl proxy. this wil provide me an access remotly.

If somone else will execute ssh -L localhost:8001:127.0.0.1:8001 @ kubectl proxy then it will get an error. "error: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8001: bind: address already in use". Because somebody else is accessing kubectl proxy.

How to solve this issue. I want to access kubernetes dashboard on multiple machine at the same time.